# Capitalization of sentences in Python

Tags: python

I'm tinkering around with a simple code but I can't seem to get it down.

I want the user to enter a string in the prompt in the form of a sentence. For example:

```
hey. how are you? the c.i.a. is watching! lol.
```

And it returns:

```
Hey. How are you? The C.I.A. Is watching! Lol.
```

So it's requirements are:

1. Capitalize the first of the string if it is a letter
2. Capitalize after every period, question mark or exclamation mark
3. Capitalize the letter if there is a period after it and no letters before it

So far I only have

```
def fix_capitalization():
s = raw_input("Enter string: ")
if s[0:1] == 'a' < [char] < 'z': 
    capitalize(s)
```

The thought process on how i would do this is as follows

Capitalize(s) to capitalize the first letter, then go through the string and if there is a period, question mark or exclamation mark then the next letter will be capitalized. if there is a letter before the period and two characters before a period then capitalize the letter before the period.

Comment: "I'm tinkering around with a simple code" Please show this code

Comment: Edit your answer to add this information. Don't add it in comment.

Comment: So there are a bunch of steps needed to get you from the current code to your solution. Even if you don't know how to code them, can you list what they might be?

Answer (score 7):

The code below matches your 3 rules. But I think your rules are not complete. The character 'i' in 'is' matches rule 2,  but it shouldn't be captialized.

```
import re

def uppercase(matchobj):
    return matchobj.group(0).upper()

def capitalize(s):
    return re.sub('^([a-z])|[\.|\?|\!]\s*([a-z])|\s+([a-z])(?=\.)', uppercase, s)

s = """hey. how are you? the c.i.a. is watching! lol. """
print capitalize(s)
```

Output:

```
Hey. How are you? The C.I.A. Is watching! Lol.
```

Answer (score 3):

This an improvement over Timothy Zhang's answer, correctly dealing with a few more cases. See the inline comments. That said, dealing with all the exceptions and oddities in capitalization is a pretty complex linguistic problem. It's probably better to use a premade solution (someone suggested the Python Natural Language Toolkit, NLTK) or to avoid this problem altogether.

```
import re

s1 = "hey. how are you? the c.i.a. is watching! lol."

print re.sub(r"(\A\w)|"+                  # start of string
             "(?<!\.\w)([\.?!] )\w|"+     # after a ?/!/. and a space, 
                                          # but not after an acronym
             "\w(?:\.\w)|"+               # start/middle of acronym
             "(?<=\w\.)\w",               # end of acronym
             lambda x: x.group().upper(), 
             s1)
```

> Hey. How are you? The C.I.A. is watching! Lol.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as simple as it seems, but let's say you are only looking for a simple solution that will work in simple cases (otherwise, you will need something like [NLTK](http://nltk.org/) which is much more complicated).

In the simplest case, what you need is to identify which letter to capitalize, extract them capitalize them et inject them back.

There are several ways to do it, but most of them will use the position of the letter and the punctuation as indentification factors.

Try to play with loops, replace, regular expressions, and post your results by editing your questions.

Comment: With replace, can I replace say ". (the beginning letter of a word)" with ". upper(the word)"

Comment: No, but you but you an create this logique with some boolean logic and a loop, or using a regular expression replacement.